# How do I determine two variables given the value of their usage in multiple equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given that it's been well over a decade and a half I don't even know how to properly phrase the math question I've run into.

I'm trying to solve for two unknown (but assumed to be whole) numbers, $x$ and $y$, given their use in multiple equations, where all other variables are known.

For example,

$x * 21.29 + y = 13$

$x * 30.27 + y = 21$

(Although technically the results are approximate, so the solution to the first equation is $13 <= a < 14$, and the first known numbers are cut off to two decimal points here.)

From what little I remember I assume that I would want to get one variable alone on one side of the equation, but I'm getting stuck when solving for $x$ (and feel pretty dumb because of it).

My equations seem to be the following, where I know $a$ and have an approximate value for $b$:

$x * a + y = b$

This then gives me:

$x * a = b - y$

$x * a - b = -y$

$y = -(x * a) + b$

Solving instead for $x$:

$x * a = b - y$

$x = \frac{b - y}{a}$

Substituting what I know $y$ equals:

$x = \frac{b - (-(x * a) + b)}{a}$

$x = \frac{b + ((x * a) + b)}{a}$

$x = \frac{2b + (x * a)}{a}$

$x = \frac{2b}{a} + \frac{(x * a)}{a}$

$x = \frac{2b}{a} + x$

$x - x = \frac{2b}{a}$

$0 = \frac{2b}{a}$

Which suggests I'm either doing the math wrong, or this method doesn't help for what I'm trying to do.

Is it possible to solve for $x$ and $y$ given what I know above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can subtract the first equation from the second to get rid of $y$ and hence solve for $x$:

$$8.98 x = 8 \\ x = \frac{8}{8.98}$$

Then pick one of the equations and substitute $x$ in to get $y$:

$$y=13-\frac{8}{8.98} \cdot 21.29.$$

Is this what you need?